# "a leader able to solve humanity's shared issues" - is "able" right word?

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to say this?

> This undergradute program would teach me to become a leader **able** to solve humanity's shared issues.

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but very awkward. Is that really what you want to say? Why not just "I want to solve humanity's shared issues"? If there are extra nuances you want to convey, you can improve your question by explaining these details.

Comment: Simple yes-or-no questions don't usually fare too well here. At the very least, you should explain **why** you think this might not work; this would make the question clearer and more interesting, and it would make our answers more helpful to you. See our [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) for more helpful tips.

Comment: Actually, I want to say something like this: "This undergraduate program would teach me to become a leader able to solve humanity's shared issues"

Comment: How does that repetition improve the question (apart from the spelling correction)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that sentence is grammatical and perfectly comprehensible. Unlike one of the comments, I do not find it stylistically awkward although it is perhaps slightly stilted. What I suspect that comment is getting at is that the sentence sounds adolescently pretentious and that therefore it might be socially advisable to modify it. But telling you what to say is not our job.

Comment: To be fair, the comment was referring to an [earlier version](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/655a355e-53ea-4ff4-ab62-50f045491513/view-source) of the question – although your opinion could apply to both versions.